# Rails Engine not loading from gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello I am new to Rails Engine , I have followed ruby official documentation for "Creating Rails Engine"  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html  After creating Plugin I have added plugin name in gemfile to load the engine

```
gem 'product_search', :path => 'product_search/engines/product_search'
```

but it always through error The path `/var/www/sites/web_service/product_search/engines/product_search` does not exist.

The Plugin name is "ProductSearch"
I have also changes the pathname

```
gem 'product_search', :path => 'ProductSearch/engines/product_search'
```

[It is the Directory structure of the plugin:]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRh1X.png

Thanks in advance..!!!

Answer (score 2):

[From the documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#inside-an-engine):

> **At the root of this brand new engine's directory lives a
>   blorgh.gemspec file**. When you include the engine into an application
>   later on, you will do so with this line in the Rails application's
>   Gemfile:

```
gem 'blorgh', path: "vendor/engines/blorgh"
```

> Don't forget to run bundle install as usual. By specifying it as a gem
>   within the Gemfile, **Bundler will load it as such, parsing this
>   blorgh.gemspec file and requiring a file within the lib directory
>   called lib/blorgh.rb**. This file requires the blorgh/engine.rb file
>   (located at lib/blorgh/engine.rb) and defines a base module called
>   Blorgh.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply..... can you please tell me what would be the gem path inside Gemfile in my case gem 'blorgh', path: "vendor/engines/blorgh"  Because I have tried many times but it did not work for me, is this file (lib/blorgh/engine.rb) goes inside the ProductSearch/lib/product_search/engine.rb am I right ?

Comment: can you check the folder structure  because inside the root lib/ folder I have not put any files from my Plugin, Here is the image http://i.stack.imgur.com/hRh1X.png

Comment: The engine can be in any place of your system,  _please don't be lazy_, read my answer, according it, the `path:` option in the Gemfile should point to the `HERE_IS_YOUR_PLUGIN_NAME.gemspec` Exactly the second part `By specifying it as a gem within the Gemfile, Bundler will load it as such, parsing this blorgh.gemspec file and requiring a file within the lib directory called lib/blorgh.rb. This file requires the blorgh/engine.rb file (located at lib/blorgh/engine.rb) and defines a base module called Blorgh.`